# kernel crashed while running tensorflow neural model. gpu is detected but some error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nvidia

I tried integrating my GPU with my TensorFlow using cuda toolkit and cudnn. Now the TensorFlow is detecting the GPU if I use `tf.is_gpu_available`. But while running the script it says following error:

```
Epoch 1/30
Cannot execute code, session has been disposed. Please try restarting the Kernel.
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

I tried upgrading the TensorFlow version from 2.10 to the latest but cuda support is not there.

Comment: `cuda support is not there.`, but you claim that `tf.is_gpu_available`. Your error does not mention anything GPU or CUDA specific. Are there any other errors that you are seeing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @Balasuriya R, Which systemOS are you using and how did you install Tensorflow in your system? Could you please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) as per your system OS to setup Tensorflow with GPU by verify and following the **Hardware/Sowftware requiremnets** and **step by step instructions** mentioned. [is_gpu_available()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available) is deprecated to use. You can use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead to check for GPU existence. Thank you